# How to move products from subcategory to its root category in magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

how to move products from  subcategory to its root category with out editing each product? Currently root category doesn't contain any product and subcategory contains 58 Products. I need to delete the subcategory and move its products to root category. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This thread on SO might help if you are determined to do it programmatically;

[Copy and Paste Category in Magento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3064494/copy-and-paste-category-in-magento)

I have to say, for only 58 products I would just spend 10 minutes and do it in the admin interface personally.  For completeness here's how that's done;

You'd go into Catalogue->Manage Categories and then click on your root category to edit it.  The go into the Category Products tab and hit the 'Reset Filter' button to display all the products. Select the ones you want and then Save the Category and delete the sub category.